# Shrinkwrap modifier doesn't show hole when applied onto the mesh

Tags: modifiers

I'm following a tutorial and got confused by the instructor what he's showing. He's shrinkwrapping the bad topology which has a hole into the good topology. Im also doing the same, but when I apply the shrinkwrap modifier it seems better topology but the hole is not cut out.

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: Hi Moonboots, I think the problem was I didnt hide  the mesh, and I believe that was the fix. or maybe I'm incorrect. https://ibb.co/ByHX2NL

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=EEyqGqrB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/EEyqGqrB/)

Comment: if I apply the modifier there's still the hole, so I'm not sure what's your problem

Comment: The problem was when I applied the shrink-wrap the hole didn't appear. In the instructional video it shows the good mesh not having a whole in it. But the instructor doesn't mention about turning off the layer so the hole is visible when its shrinkwrapped.

Comment: He's using older version of Blender, so I assume now he turns off the mesh with the good topology and the hole is visible: https://ibb.co/TPgPx3L

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem, but have you fixed it? Other than that it looks like you need to add a bit of topology if you want to have no pinching around the corners of the hole, so maybe apply a Subdivision Surface with a level of 1 then apply the Shrinkwrap